# Auto-populate a cell with a date when another cell is populated

Tags: apple-numbers, apple-numbers-formula

In Excel I can add the following formula...

```
=IF(A1="", "", IF(B1="", NOW(), B1))
```

This formula says when a value in added to cell A1 populate cell B1 with the current date. To get this to work you must turn on an Excel feature named iterative calculation (Options==>Formulas==>Enable iterative calculation).

I use this when I'm building an Excel task journal and I want to auto-populate the date.

The important thing about this formula is that the date value is not updated if another change is made.

In Numbers, how can I auto populate a date value in column "B" when a value is set in column "A"? It's important to keep in mind that once the date is set I don't want it to change.

Here is my attempt at translating this formula in Apple Numbers.

```
=IF(A2="", "", IF(B2="", NOW(), B2))
```

I get an error message.

> This formula can't reference its own cell, or depend on another formula that references this cell

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution for this? I'm in the same boat…

Comment: I posted this question on Ask Different and I have not yet found a solution. My guess is that this is a feature that Numbers does not support.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the response.